# Why am I receiving Internal Server Error and this list of errors and what should I focus on to fix the errors I am receiving?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A controller which returns names of which surname start with the letter given in the method.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using AdminController.Models;

    namespace AdminController.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public IActionResult Index(string letter)
            {
                string query = "";
                if(letter != null) { query = letter; }

                List<Student> studenten = new List<Student>()
                {
                 new Student { Naam = "Johan", Achternaam = "Jacobs" },
                 new Student { Naam = "Karel", Achternaam = "Jay" },
                 new Student { Naam = "John", Achternaam = "Jas" }
                };
                List<Student> NieuwStudenten = null;
                NieuwStudenten = studenten.Where(x => x.Achternaam.StartsWith(query) == true).ToList();

                ViewData["NieuwStudenten"] = NieuwStudenten;

                return View(NieuwStudenten);
        }


    }
    }



// View
    @using AdminController.Models;
    @model AdminController.Models.Student;

    @{var lijst = (List<Student>)ViewData["NieuwStudenten"];}

    <html>

    <body>
    @foreach (var item in lijst)
    {
        <h1>
            @item.Naam, @item.Achternaam
        </h1>
    }
    </body>

    </html>


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace AdminController.Models
    {
        public class Student
        {
            public string Naam { get; set; }
            public string Achternaam { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

These are the errors I'm receiving.

```
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Generated Code

Syntax error, ',' expected
+
    public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<AdminController.Models.Student;>
Syntax error, '>' expected
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
+
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<AdminController.Models.Student;> Html { get; private set; }
Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
+
}
A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
+
        public override async Task ExecuteAsync()
'<invalid-global-code>.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override
+
        public override async Task ExecuteAsync()
'_Views_Home_Index_cshtml' does not implement inherited abstract member 'RazorPage.ExecuteAsync()'
+
    public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<AdminController.Models.Student;>
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(0, 2, true);
The name 'WriteLiteral' does not exist in the current context
+
            WriteLiteral("\r\n");
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(130, 2, true);
The name 'WriteLiteral' does not exist in the current context
+
            WriteLiteral("\r\n");
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(265, 20, true);
The name 'WriteLiteral' does not exist in the current context
+
            WriteLiteral("\r\n<html>\r\n\r\n<body>\r\n");
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(318, 18, true);
The name 'WriteLiteral' does not exist in the current context
+
            WriteLiteral("    <h1>\r\n        ");
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(337, 9, false);
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(346, 2, true);
The name 'WriteLiteral' does not exist in the current context
+
            WriteLiteral(", ");
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(349, 15, false);
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(364, 13, true);
The name 'WriteLiteral' does not exist in the current context
+
            WriteLiteral("\r\n    </h1>\r\n");
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();
The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            BeginContext(380, 18, true);
The name 'WriteLiteral' does not exist in the current context
+
            WriteLiteral("</body>\r\n\r\n</html>");
The name 'EndContext' does not exist in the current context
+
            EndContext();

Show compilation source
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context
+
@{var lijst = (List<Student>)ViewData["NieuwStudenten"];}
The name 'Write' does not exist in the current context
+
        @item.Naam, @item.Achternaam
The name 'Write' does not exist in the current context
+
        @item.Naam, @item.Achternaam
```

OF COURSE I'm not expecting anyone to fix this code or check all errors for me my question specifically actually is what am I doing wrong and why am I receiving all these errors and which direction should I go on to correct them?
I'm very new to MVC and C# and my situation is that I'm basically not able to understand what's going wrong.

Thank you for your input and as reminder I'm not expecting you to do slave labor for me all I need is a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you facing this kind of error , go to developer tool in IE(click F12) and than go to Network click start button. you can see the HTTP response Code. Click any response code(ex : 500) and than go to response body, you can get error details. I hope this will help you lot. find the attached image, you can understand clearly.

Comment: I did but there are no response codes to click a start button with. What's going on

Comment: Please Explain the process how you did it?

Comment: F12 Inspecting the website and I see in network just nothing. I'm totally lost on how I should approach this problem

Comment: click start button under network . you can find the response code